HOW TO INSTALL VISUAL STUDIO CODE on MAC OS 10.14(.6)?
I can't upgrade my macbook. I'm stuck with os 10.14.6.
Is there a way to find a version of Visual Studio Code to download that would work on mac os 10.14 ?
I did start a qa testing formation and i want to keep practicing at home for test automation.

Have you at least tried to download the current version and try to install it? What happens when you do?

Also, have you tried any of the previous versions that are still available?

You will struggle to install a lot of software if you can't stay up to date with the OS.
You may be able to upgrade your OS. See https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/ I have done this successfully on a number of Macs

If all else fails, you can use the online version of VS Code, you can even work with local files: https://vscode.dev
